# How to remove Print to File printer?

Tags: printing

How to remove **Print to File** printer?

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to remove it? It is there because your system does not think you have an actual printer.

Comment: In my case, it would be useful for me to completely ban printing. Removing this printer could be the first step.

Comment: Not sure you can but it only makes a file on the local HDD not any kind of hard copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file

```
libprintbackend-file.so
```

is responsible for this. Do a `locate libprintbackend-file.so` and rename it to test out if this works. It will be in a directory like this:

```
/usr/lib/gtk-*.0/*/printbackends/
```

where the * denotes the gtk version.

In case you use snaps each snap might also return a version. Doing that on those files also removes the option "Print to file" from that specific snap.

Comment: A system update  would likely replace the file that has been moved out of the way. It is difficult to comprehend why this is an acceptable answer.

Comment: He does not want to remove cups. He wants to remove the option to "print to file". There is no setting to do that. This is of course a hack and yes it might get restored but it does what he asked for and that is why it was accepted ;-)

Comment: There is no way to remove *Print to File* from a GTK print dialog using what the system legitimately provides? I think my answer addresses that point and refutes the assertion. If the answer is not clear enough, please let me know and I will consider amending it.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating a library file on the system, even as a test, is not the best of ideas and is highly unlikely to lead to a satisfactory or long-term solution. I would suggest becoming faniliar with what is handled by `gtk-print-backends` in `GtkSettings`.

I'll give you what I use system-wide on one of my machines:

`josie@laptop:~$ cat /etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`
`[Settings]`

`gtk-print-backends=cups`

BTW, as already said, `Print to File` has nothing to do with the printing system. Also, if you wish to completely ban printing, why not remove cups, cups-daemon, cups-filters etc from the system?

Comment: "BTW, as already said, Print to File has nothing to do with the printing system. "  but that is what he wants removed ;-)